# How to fade out an object?

Tags: animation, mesh, materials, modifiers, transparency

I want to make an object slowly disappear in order to reveal the background. The only way I know to do this is to animate a transparent BSDF. In my case, this is not very handy because the object has multiple materials.

Isn't there a way to affect the mesh itself?
Like a modifier or something like that?

Comment: If you want it to disappear by becoming more transparent, no, there is no way.  You could make it disappear by scaling it to make it ever smaller, or by using shape keys to cause it to collapse, but those both appear to be movement of the object.

Comment: yes, there's no a direct way but you could animate BSDF Alpha, and it should work in Eevee and Cycles... it's not that complex, maybe set up a driver to use an object as a switch, or have the animation inside a node group so it's a single place to edit... also you can use compositor or just mix 2 video, it depends... here's a [test setup](https://www.dropbox.com/s/5rq20wsqym3zdh7/alphas.blend?dl=1) anyway

Comment: You can also use a different view layer with just the objects you want to fade and play with the alpha over value in compositing after rendering

Answer (score 2, accepted):

this is NOT a fading but...a maybe working workaround for you if you are not to fixated on one solution.

e.g. you could use a geometry node tree like this:

[image]

then keyframe the probability from 1 to 0....

to get this:

[image]

or you just use the build modifier reversed:

[image]

[image]

...and of course you could write a python script which runs over all your materials and adds a mixed node with a transparent node in front of your material output and animates the mix factor.

Answer (score 0):

I know it has been one year, but I actually manage to create this effect by adding a mix shader just before the Material Output node, and mixing a zero alpha principled BSDF with my complex material. The I just need to animate the Mix Shader factor going from 1 (my material) to 0 (the zero alpha material)

Comment: Your solution is functional, but not applicable in this context, where there are too many materials to deal with.